# how I execute create view query using DataContext of apache meta modal?

Tags: java, apache, oracle11g, export-to-csv, apache-metamodel

I have created a sample program using the `DataContext` class to get records from an `oracle11g` table, and write its data to CSV file.

Here is my code for getting table and write into a CSV.

```
  UpdateableDataContext dataContext = DataContextFactory.createCsvDataContext(tmpCSV);
    TableCreationBuilder table = callback.createTable(getDataContext().getDefaultSchema(),"Table1").execute();
    RowInsertionBuilder insert = callback.insertInto(table);
   //we are getting each column from each record and than run
           insert.value("columnName","value")
//After inserting all records we are execute below command to insert data into csv
           insert.execute();
```

I want to do the same thing with creating a view, and putting its data into a CSV file.

How can I use `DataContext` in java for creating views, and then writing the view's data into a CSV file?